# Chrome: Positioning issue with placeholder in password field

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm facing an issue with Chrome (and only with Chrome) and a password input field with placeholder.

The following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jF78/1/) shows my source code - 3 password fields and one text field (with the right alignment), no styles, no JavaScript.

```
<input id="1" name="Password1" placeholder="Test" type="password"><br />
<input id="2" name="Password2" placeholder="Test Test" type="password"><br />
<input id="3" name="Password3" placeholder="Test Test Test" type="password"><br />
<input id="4" name="Text1" placeholder="Test" type="text">
```

In chrome (Version Version 29.0.1547.66 m) on Windows 2K8 it looks like this:

[image: Password box on chrome]

The space on the left side of the box goes along with the length of the placeholder string. Further on it's not possible to click inside that space area to activate the field.

Is anyone else facing this issue? Any ideas or solutions? A bug, a feature, ...

Best regards

Comment: Fiddle looks ok on Chrome 29 (OS X).

Comment: Also looks OK on Chrome 29 at WinXP.

Comment: And in Chrome Canary 31.0.1636.2 on Win 7.

Comment: It seems there is a similar bug filed in chromium https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253712&q=placeholder%20password&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified.

Comment: same issue found on Version 30.0.1599.101 m windows 8. did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it, bug is caused by the experimental password generation feature.
disable it here: chrome://flags/#enable-password-generation